# "Shop by" / "layered navigation" configurable products not filtering correctly

Tags: product, configurable-product, ce-1.8.1.0, layered-navigation

For example. You have t-shirts with size and color.
You have a configurable product t-shirt with a number of variations on these attributes as simple products.

When filtering using "shop by" and you have say a "red small" and a "green medium" shirt but no "red medium", if try filter by "red" and "medium" the configurable product will be displayed even though no such combination exists within the configurable product.

Is there a option or fix to get the correct behavior?

Using 1.8.1.0 Community Edition and SCP (Simple Configurable Products).

Comment: I read this question already, but I can't find it. And I'm not sure whether the other question had a solution for this.

Comment: Thanks!. Wording of other [question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17408/magento-layered-navigation-filters-for-grouped-products) was a bit different and couldn't originally find it.

Comment: Damn, no answer. I thought I wrote more there. I'll add some informations to my answer about how I would approach the problem... Ok I thought about it and it is a tough problem. No idea how to approach :(

Comment: I was just surprised it doesn't work out of the box. I would think it's a VERY common requirement. Then again the lack of support of proper/good configurable/group/hierarchical product system is also an issue. i.e. the need for SCP and BCP extensions. I should check if BCP perhaps addresses the issue - somewhat related.

Comment: I think his proposal is probably the best/cleanest approach. Implementation however could be quite a pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently does not seem to be any existing solution, or extensions available. SCP and BCP extensions don't resolve this issue either.

Requires custom coding as described in the linked question.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not (out of the box!).

When the index is built, *ALL* simple products are fetched (regardless if active or not) and all searchable, filterable, ... attributes are index (one by one), so there is no option to have your intended behaviour.

More infos can be found in `\Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext::_prepareProductIndex`